# Is it possible to store variables in a collection?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have three variables of any type. Is it possible to store them in a collection so that when I assign a value to an element in this collection, it is the corresponding variable that is changed ?

**Example :** In the code below, when the value of `isButton[0]` changes, the value of `isButtonOne` remains of course always the same. So I'm wondering if there's a way to assign a new value to the `isButtonOne` variable. More generally, is it possible to store variables in a collection so that the elements in this collection are not the values of the variables, but are the variables themselves?

```
static bool isButtonOne;
static bool isButtonTwo;
static bool isButtonThree;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool[] isButton = new bool[] { isButtonOne, isButtonTwo, isButtonThree }
    isButton[0] = true;
}
```

Comment: You cannot store "variables" in a collection. However, you can use reference type objects instead of `bool` primitives in order to provide such behaviour. In general, I am 99% sure that you actually don't need this and this code can be rewritten in a better way without unnatural reference types. Why would you need these `isButtonOne`, `isButtonTwo`, `isButtonThree` variables at all? Just use an array.

Comment: Ok please can you send me a link about this so I can learn more ? - @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand well : "You can use reference type objects instead of bool primitives in order to provide such behaviour." Can you explain in code Please ? - @YeldarKurmangaliyev